# I m Trying to run apache tomcat server with https it is giving me error like This site can’t be reached localhost took too long to respond

Tags: tomcat

I created certificate for ssl  and when I m Trying to run apache tomcat server with https it is giving me error like This site can’t be reached localhost took too long to respond.

Comment: please provide your tomcat configuration, and the steps you took to configure it.

Comment: I created dummy certificate through keytool which is in jdk

Comment: i reffered this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVt6g5AZ6ko